# Plotting one data set with two unrelated y axes-matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot one data set with two different unrelated y axes. I've tried using twinx, but that just makes two plots on the same graph. I want there to be one point corresponding to two y values.

This is what I have so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[range(1,16)] 
y=[13.03,13.03,13.03,13.04,13.04,13.05,13.05,13.07,13.07,13.10,13.10,13.13,13.18‌​,13.23,13.39] 
y2=[6.944,6.964,6.972,7.008,7.045,7.085,7.109,7.213,7.215,7.5,7.51,7.73,8.2,8.68‌​,11.09] 
fig, ax1=plt.subplots() 

ax1.set_xlabel("Time",fontsize=14) 
ax1.set_ylabel("Lookback Time\nGly",fontsize=14) 
ax2=ax1.twinx() 
ax2.set_ylabel("z",fontsize=14) 
ax1.set_ylim(13.00,13.40) 
ax2.set_ylim(6.800,11.200) 
ax1.set_xlim(0,16) 
ax1.scatter(x,y, label="Lookback Time", s=80,color='b' )#marker='^') ax2.scatter(x,y2, label="z", s=80,color="r")

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you include the code you've written so far?

Comment: Why not use two axis but just plot in one (leaving the other empty)? http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html

Comment: @wogsland This is what I have so far: x=[range(1,16)]
y=[13.03,13.03,13.03,13.04,13.04,13.05,13.05,13.07,13.07,13.10,13.10,13.13,13.18,13.23,13.39]
y2=[6.944,6.964,6.972,7.008,7.045,7.085,7.109,7.213,7.215,7.5,7.51,7.73,8.2,8.68,11.09]


fig, ax1=plt.subplots()
ax1.set_xlabel("Time",fontsize=14)
ax1.set_ylabel("Lookback Time\nGly",fontsize=14)
ax2=ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylabel("z",fontsize=14)

ax1.set_ylim(13.00,13.40)
ax2.set_ylim(6.800,11.200)
ax1.set_xlim(0,16)
 

ax1.scatter(x,y, label="Lookback Time", s=80,color='b' )#marker='^')
ax2.scatter(x,y2, label="z", s=80,color="r")

Comment: I usually look through the [matplotlib gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) till I find something that looks close to or has a feature that I want, then play around with it. This one might work: [two_scales](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).